# Multiple object detection using SURF features in MATLAB?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, surf, matlab-cvst

I have training sets of each of the indivdual objects shown in this following image. This one image is also the query image:
[image]
Four of these training sets have 18 images each, consisting of images cropped down and taken at different angles. I also have another training set of another object. That object should not be detected with this queried image.

Objective: Identify all of the objects in the query image. Could be any uniform background, hoping to go toward any background also (cluttered scene, random background).
My research and questions:

1. Should I be using the cascade object detection which uses the Viola-Jone algoritm and discount SURF features? I would give negative examples in this case.
2. Use KNN (k=2) method? I tried using this and the accuracy isn't that great.
3. Use SVM? Don't know to much about this but I know that it has something to do with bag of features...
4. Just use matchFeatures function iterative and set up a ratio of number of features matched over the number of features in a training set.

Final question: I need some direction toward my objective. Any links and direction would be greatly appreciated. If you refer me to one of my four notes I made, please explain.

Comment: See [NBNN classifier](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~irani/PAPERS/InDefenceOfNN_CVPR08.pdf), you might also want to use descriptors that do not discard color information.